# Running JUnit tests ignoring module path

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, java-module

I'm working on an existing maven-based Java project to support Java Module (JPMS). So far I had no problem defining new modules and their dependencies with files info-module.java, but I still have problems when I try to run unit tests from Eclipse.

Test code follows the usual folder and package scheme for Maven projects: code is inside *src/test/java* folder and replicates the package structure of application code.

When I try to run a JUnit test case from Eclipse, I receive a lot of errors about missing modules or not visible packages. What I like to do now is running unit test using only Java classpath and ignoring module path. With Maven and Surefire plugin it's pretty straightforward as I can use option **useModulePath** to ignore module path.

I also know that IntelliJ as an option called 'Do not use --module-path option' which does exactly what I need.

Do you now any equivalent option or workaround for Eclipse to obtain this behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please.

Comment: In menu "Run->Run Configurations" you can add command line options. Did you try: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm#module-dependencies

Comment: @howlger sorry for my late reply. I just opened Maven module wicket-core of project Apache Wicket (https://github.com/apache/wicket), branch wicket-9x. Than I tried to run junit tests from Eclipse but it failed  due to missing modules or not visible packages. I'm using the workaround described in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I've found a workaround which works fine for me. I want to make clear that it's a workaround and it's not something comparable to the Intellij feature I talk about in the question.
Basically I filtered file **module-info.java** in 'Java Build Path' options:

[image]

In this way Eclipse ignores module path and uses only the old classpath.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-2F61F3A9-0979-46A4-8B49-325BA0EE8B66

Look for the Runtime Option **--add-opens** and use it to give the reflective access that JUnit or TestNG etc need to the whitebox testing build.

It looks like this will not improve in the short term. Build tools like Gradle have packaged this up to make it less painful.

Comment: Proper support for whitebox testing in JPMS appears to have been dropped or become conflated with restricting reflection access (i.e. muddled) between the Requirements (see *Development*) and the Specification phases of the JPMS project. It wasn't picked up in the spec review minutes I read on OpenJDK with any real vigour. Huge projects such as JPMS are always hard. It must have cost Oracle a fortune to implement and probably a lot more than their budget.  I guess there will be no appetite to put even more effort into fixing this shortfall soon.